# Connect to Heroku ClearDB with SpringBoot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, heroku, jdbc, cleardb

I am new to Heroku and I am trying to deploy my spring-boot application which is connecting to a MySQL database, since Heroku does not support native MySQL, I looked for an alternative in the internet for MySQL and I found ClearDB, so I created it and I was able to connect to it locally, but when I deploy it to Huroku it throws an error and refused to start,

here are the logs I got:

```
Feb 08 08:01:19 denty-auth heroku/web.1 State changed from crashed to starting
Feb 08 08:01:22 denty-auth heroku/web.1 Starting process with command `java -Dserver.port=6526 $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/denty-auth.jar`
Feb 08 08:01:23 denty-auth app/web.1 Create a Procfile to customize the command used to run this process: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile
Feb 08 08:01:23 denty-auth app/web.1 Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
Feb 08 08:01:23 denty-auth app/web.1 Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
Feb 08 08:01:25 denty-auth app/web.1   .   ____          _            __ _ _
Feb 08 08:01:25 denty-auth app/web.1  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
Feb 08 08:01:25 denty-auth app/web.1 ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
Feb 08 08:01:25 denty-auth app/web.1  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
Feb 08 08:01:25 denty-auth app/web.1   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
Feb 08 08:01:25 denty-auth app/web.1  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
Feb 08 08:01:25 denty-auth app/web.1  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.0.RELEASE)
Feb 08 08:01:25 denty-auth app/web.1 2022-02-08 16:01:24.715  INFO 4 --- [           main] com.SpringBootSecurityApplication        : Starting SpringBootSecurityApplication vdenty-auth.0.0.1 on 7e553246-f0e4-4a84-a0c4-3f329d7a720b with PID 4 (/app/target/denty-auth.jar started by u27630 in /app)
Feb 08 08:01:25 denty-auth app/web.1 2022-02-08 16:01:24.719  INFO 4 --- [           main] com.SpringBootSecurityApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
Feb 08 08:01:26 denty-auth app/web.1 2022-02-08 16:01:26.345  INFO 4 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
Feb 08 08:01:27 denty-auth app/web.1 2022-02-08 16:01:27.080  INFO 4 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 711ms. Found 2 repository interfaces.
Feb 08 08:01:27 denty-auth app/web.1 2022-02-08 16:01:27.526  INFO 4 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1 2022-02-08 16:01:27.836  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 6526 (http)
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1 2022-02-08 16:01:27.847  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1 2022-02-08 16:01:27.847  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.27]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1 2022-02-08 16:01:27.895  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1 2022-02-08 16:01:27.896  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3067 ms
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1 2022-02-08 16:01:28.508 ERROR 4 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:199) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:121) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:353) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:473) [HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:562) [HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:81) [HikariCP-3.4.1.jar!/:na]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at com.denty.config.DatabaseConfig.dataSource(DatabaseConfig.java:23) [classes!/:denty-auth.0.0.1]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at com.denty.config.DatabaseConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$adfdbc65.CGLIB$dataSource$0(<generated>) [classes!/:denty-auth.0.0.1]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at com.denty.config.DatabaseConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$adfdbc65$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$804cbe3a.invoke(<generated>) [classes!/:denty-auth.0.0.1]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) [spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) [spring-context-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at com.denty.config.DatabaseConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$adfdbc65.dataSource(<generated>) [classes!/:denty-auth.0.0.1]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_322-heroku]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_322-heroku]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_322-heroku]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_322-heroku]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:475) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:874) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:778) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:226) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:400) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth heroku/web.1 Process exited with status 1
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth heroku/web.1 State changed from starting to crashed
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) [spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at com.SpringBootSecurityApplication.main(SpringBootSecurityApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:denty-auth.0.0.1]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_322-heroku]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_322-heroku]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_322-heroku]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_322-heroku]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[denty-auth.jar:denty-auth.0.0.1]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[denty-auth.jar:denty-auth.0.0.1]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) ~[denty-auth.jar:denty-auth.0.0.1]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) ~[denty-auth.jar:denty-auth.0.0.1]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1 Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_322-heroku]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_322-heroku]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_322-heroku]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_322-heroku]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1340) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:157) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:956) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    ... 72 common frames omitted
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1 Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.<init>(HandshakeContext.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_322-heroku]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.<init>(ClientHandshakeContext.java:103) ~[na:1.8.0_322-heroku]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(TransportContext.java:220) ~[na:1.8.0_322-heroku]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:428) ~[na:1.8.0_322-heroku]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.performTlsHandshake(ExportControlled.java:316) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.performTlsHandshake(StandardSocketFactory.java:188) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.performTlsHandshake(NativeSocketConnection.java:99) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:329) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    ... 79 common frames omitted
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1 2022-02-08 16:01:28.510  WARN 4 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/denty/config/DatabaseConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Communications link failure
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1 2022-02-08 16:01:28.513  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1 2022-02-08 16:01:28.524  INFO 4 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1 Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1 2022-02-08 16:01:28.527 ERROR 4 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/denty/config/DatabaseConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Communications link failure
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:787) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at com.SpringBootSecurityApplication.main(SpringBootSecurityApplication.java:10) [classes!/:denty-auth.0.0.1]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_322-heroku]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_322-heroku]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_322-heroku]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_322-heroku]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [denty-auth.jar:denty-auth.0.0.1]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [denty-auth.jar:denty-auth.0.0.1]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51) [denty-auth.jar:denty-auth.0.0.1]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) [denty-auth.jar:denty-auth.0.0.1]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [com/denty/config/DatabaseConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Communications link failure
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:645) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    ... 36 common frames omitted
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Communications link failure
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1    ... 50 common frames omitted
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1 Caused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Communications link failure
Feb 08 08:01:28 denty-auth app/web.1 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Feb 08 08:01:29 denty-auth app/web.1    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_322-heroku]
Feb 08 08:01:29 denty-auth app/web.1    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_322-heroku]
Feb 08 08:01:29 denty-auth app/web.1    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_322-heroku]
Feb 08 08:01:29 denty-auth app/web.1    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
Feb 08 08:01:29 denty-auth app/web.1    ... 51 common frames omitted
Feb 08 08:01:29 denty-auth app/web.1 Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
Feb 08 08:01:29 denty-auth app/web.1 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Feb 08 08:01:29 denty-auth app/web.1    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar!/:8.0.18]
Feb 08 08:01:29 denty-auth app/web.1    ... 64 common frames omitted
Feb 08 08:01:29 denty-auth app/web.1 Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
Feb 08 08:01:29 denty-auth app/web.1 The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Feb 08 08:01:29 denty-auth app/web.1    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_322-heroku]
Feb 08 08:01:29 denty-auth app/web.1    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_322-heroku]
Feb 08 08:01:29 denty-auth app/web.1    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_322-heroku]
Feb 08 08:01:29 denty-auth app/web.1    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_322-heroku]
Feb 08 08:01:29 denty-auth app/web.1    ... 72 common frames omitted
Feb 08 08:01:29 denty-auth app/web.1 Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
Feb 08 08:01:29 denty-auth app/web.1    ... 79 common frames omitted
Feb 08 08:02:25 denty-auth app/api Build succeeded
```

my application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://eu-cdbr-west-02.cleardb.net/heroku_f0199c2dce52aa7?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&reconnect=true
spring.datasource.username=baf4cc3740fa70
spring.datasource.password=***************
```

my pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

can you guys help me fixing it please? :)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking a lot and finally, I found the solution,
the problem was the Java version and MySQL connector version lack of compatibility, in local, I am using a newer version of Java (17th) and in my QA I am using the 8th version,

so all I had to do is to specify the version of MySQL connector, pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.21</version>
</dependency>
```

Additional Information

- A recent Java update, specifically Red Hat/CentOS, disables TLSv1 and TLSv1.1 by default for Java 8
- The MySQL JDBC driver will attempt to use TLSv1 and/or TLSv1.1 if the MySQL database version is below one of the following: 8.0, 5.7.28, 5.6.46